# Printing dictornary with list order

Tags: python, list, dictionary, printing, format

I have the following code, it is an address book (a list of dictionaries) and a list. The idea is to print the items from the dictionary in the order of the list (since dicts mess up the order of everything). When I run this code, it throws an exception (as shown below). I am not sure what I'm doing wrong as I have tried many different variations and I keep coming back to this wondering why it's not working.

Please help?

```
addressBook = [
    {
    'Nickname': 'Jimmy',
    'Name': 'James Roberts',
    'Address': '2/50 Robe Street',
    'Phone': '0273503342'
    },
    {
    'Nickname': 'Bob',
    'Name': 'Robert',
    'Address': '1 Vivan Street',
    'Phone': '067578930'
    }
]

addressFields = ['Nickname', 'Name', 'Address', 'Phone']

def listAll(addressBook, addressFields):
    for i in addressBook:
        for key in addressFields:
            print("{0} {1}".format(key, addressBook[i][key]))

    print("{0} {1}".format(key, addressBook[i][key]))


TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're missing a `'` in the `addressBook` literal after `'James Roberts`. Second, the issue was that you were doing `addressBook[i][key]` instead of `i[key]`. `i` already refers to a dictionary contained in `addressBook`, so your code was trying to use a `list`'s element as an index to itself.

```
def listAll(addressBook, addressFields):
    for i in addressBook:
        for key in addressFields:
            print('{} {}'.format(key, i[key]))
```

Python 3-friendly one-liner:

```
def listAll(addressBook, addressFields):
    print(*('{} {}'.format(j, i[j]) for i in addressBook for j in addressFields), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively in a single line:

```
print('\n'.join(element for element in [j+" "+ i[j] for i in addressBook for j in addressFields]
))
```

Comment: You can clean that up as follows: `print(*(j+" "+ i[j] for i in addressBook for j in addressFields), sep='\n')`. The `element for element in` part is only needed if you're adding a filtering condition (which you aren't in this case).

Comment: FWIW, it's better to use `.join` on a list comp than on a gen exp: if you feed it a gen exp it has to convert it to a list. The reason `.join` does that is that it has to scan the data twice: once to determine the total string length required & then again to actually build the string. If it didn't do the double scan it'd have to build the output string using repeated string concatenation, which is very wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

addressBook = [{'Nickname': 'Jimmy', 'Name': 'James Roberts', 'Address': '2/50 Robe Street', 'Phone': '0273503342'},{'Nickname': 'Bob', 'Name': 'Robert', 'Address': '1 Vivan Street', 'Phone': '067578930'}]

addressFields = ['Nickname', 'Name', 'Address', 'Phone']

def listAll(addressBook, addressFields):
  for i in addressBook:
    for val in addressFields:
      print("{0} {1}".format(val, i[val]))

listAll(addressBook, addressFields)
```

Answer (score -1):

After posting this question I found the answer.

I converted the addressBook for loop to a range(len(addressBook)) and it worked.

```
for i in range(len(addressBook)):
```

Comment: In Python, `for i in range(len(x))` is rarely the right way to go. The issue wasn't how you were setting up the loop, but what you were doing inside it.